# Derived Column Editor

Tags: ssis

I need to assign a formatted date to a column in a data flow. I have added a Derived shape and entered the following expression for a NEW column - Derived Column = "add as new column":

```
"BBD" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,4)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),1,4) + 
SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,2)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),6,2) + 
SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,2)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),9,2)
```

The problem is that the *Derived Column Transformation Editor* automatically assigns a Data Type of `Unicode string[DT_WSTR]` and a length of "7". Howver, the length of a string is 11, therefore the following exception is thrown each time:

```
[Best Before Date [112]] Error: The "component "Best Before Date" (112)" failed 
because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column
"Comments" (132)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred 
on the specified object of the specified component.
```

Does anyone know why the edit is insisting on a length of 7? I don't seem to be able to change this.

Many thanks,

Rob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't understand why SSIS is measuring that column as only resulting in a seven character field - but to force it to provide an 11 character column for it, modify your expression slightly to this:

**(DT_WSTR, 11)(**"BBD" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,4)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),1,4) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,2)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),6,2) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,2)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),9,2)**)**

Comment: Hi Todd, I think that's what I said in my earlier comment.

Regarding the default length of 7: I did notice that the first concatenation (the 3-char string plus the first substring) results in 7 chars.
@Rob: could it be that you initially had a different expression for that field, resulting in 7 characters?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
"BBD" + (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE())) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE())),2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE())),2)
```

The issue is in how you are converting your dates to a string.  The calls to DATEADD return a full date & time.  Next, you then have either (DT_WSTR,4) or (DT_WSTR,2) to convert that date into either a 4 or 2 character string.  On my system, converting a datetime to a string defaults to "Aug 24 2011 4:18PM".  So the first 4 characters gets you "Aug " and the first 2 characters gets you "Au".  Then, you are extracting substrings using SUBSTRING.  For your last two calls to SUBSTRING, you are starting the substring past the end of the 2 character string you converted the date into.  This is why SSIS displays 7 characters:

```
"BBD" + "Aug " + "" + ""
  3   +    4   +  0 +  0  =  7
```

It is better to use the built in functions to extract the Year, Month and Day from a datetime rather than converting to a string and then grabbing substrings.  If you really wanted to use substrings, you would need to add a call to CONVERT to get the datetime to a specific string format, otherwise you will get whatever the default is for your locale setting in Windows.  This could be different on each PC.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on "Derived Column" open "Show Advanced Editor" Select "Input and output Properties" tab.
Got to "Derived column output" => "Output Columns" => "Derived Column 1" (added by you)

In right side panel go to "Data type Properties"  section=> DataType=>

Select "String [DT_STR]

### click OK[Image showing steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU2pF.png)

This will solve your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you replacing your existing field, and is that field possibly 7 chars long?  The thing with the Derived Column Transform is that you can't change the field types (including length) of the existing fields.

Try to add a new field instead.

If that's not working, try adding an explicit cast around the whole expression.

```
(DT_WSTR,11)("BBD" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,4)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),1,4) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,2)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),6,2) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,2)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),9,2))
```

Comment: No, I have <Add as new Column> set

Comment: I see. How about adding an explicit cast around the whole expression?

(DT_WSTR,11)("BBD" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,4)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),1,4) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,2)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),6,2) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,2)DATEADD("Day",30,GETDATE()),9,2))

Comment: BTW: SSIS knows the DATEPART function which can be used instead of those SUBSTRINGs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137586.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What release and service pack of SQL are you using?

I just tried this on my machine and had no problems changing the result size from 7 to 11.   Is it possible that you have not installed all the service packs?

Comment: In SQL 2008 you can no longer change the data type manually, you need to explicitly cast it to whatever you need.